# ActiveJob: Full strack trace despite rescue_from block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rails-activejob

I have a vanilla Rails app that consists just of a simple `Post` model with a title and a content attribute.

I took the `ActiveJob` exception example from [the official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions), which looks as follows:

```
class ExceptionTestJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  rescue_from(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) do |exception|
    logger.error("Could not find given post")
  end

  def perform(post_id)
    post = Post.find(post_id)
  end
end
```

If I try to run the job with a post id that doesn’t exist, I get the full stack trace and the error message "Could not find given post".

I do not want to get the stack trace. I just want to get the code executed that's in the `rescue_from` block. How do I suppress the stack trace?

**Edit**:

If I use the regular `rescue` inside the method like this:

```
class ExceptionTestJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(post_id)
    begin
      Post.find(post_id)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      logger.error("Could not find given post")
    end
  end
end
```

the exception will get caught without the backtrace (like intended), but the job will finish as successful: `Performed ExceptionTestJob (Job ID: c21ce397-b19b-4464-9e53-696707b87dde) from Async(default) in 13.84ms`.

Comment: as per my understanding, your rescue_from block code is running. what you want next can you please more explain that?

Comment: I dont' want my logs to get polluted with the whole stack trace. I just want the short error message from the rescue_from block there.

Comment: Fabian, except the log, what kind of response do you want?

Comment: In the end just the log.

Comment: It's a shame this question hasn't been resolved. This is still an issue with ActiveJob

Comment: My current work around for this is to raise an exception that return an empty backtrace.

Answer (score -2):

I think it will help you

```
begin
  raise
rescue => e
  logger.error e.message
  logger.error e.backtrace.join("\n")
end
```